# «Bless you» in Brazilian

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia, português-brasileiro

There is a special form (like a slang word) in brazilian for *bless you*.

It sounds like "sanutsch". But I can't remember.

Anyone know what I mean?

Comment: After you sneeze, you mean? That would be *saúde*, which most people pronounce *saúdji*.

Comment: In Germany they say "Gesundheit" which means "saúde" in Portuguese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use |Saúde| wich is the same as health, to wish someone health.
Pronounce is |Saúdji| or saúdi. and SAÚDE is how you write it

Comment: Ele foi específico quanto a palavra que procurava, mas para abençoar alguns ainda usam "Deus te abençoe". Saúde se diz para alguém que espirra.

Comment: Sim, isso se aplica mais numa igreja por exemplo, mas no respeito ao que ele diz é Saúde.

Answer (score 2):

In Portugal, we manly use 'Santinho !' or fewer times 'Saúde.' (Maybe in Lisbon the previous is more common) . Some people (older generations) use 'Benza-te deus!'Tha later translates directrly to god bless you.